# PHP - merge/combine array values in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, merge

How could I convert this array:

```
$a = array(
 0 => array(
     0 => 31,
     1 => 39
 ),
 1 => array(
     0 => 41
 )
);
```

to this one:

```
   $a = array(
    0 => array(
        0 => array(
            0 => 31,
            1 => 41
        ),
        1 => array(
            0 => 39,
            1 => 41
        )
    ),
    1 => array(
        0 => array(
            0 => 41,
            1 => 31
        ),
        1 => array(
            0 => 41,
            1 => 39
        )
    )
);
```

I tried several ways, but find no proper solution. At the moment my brain is overheated. So maybe someone has a solution for me.

Thanks @Manos.

Unfortunatly there are dynamic arrays. So these static function wont work for me.

So the array could also look like this:

```
$a = array(
 0 => array(
     0 => 31,
     1 => 39
 ),
 1 => array(
     0 => 41,
     1 => 49,
     2 => 51
 ),
 2 => array(
     0 => 73
 )
);
```

Output should look like this:

```
   $a = array(
        0 => array(
            0 => array(
                0 => 31,
                1 => 41,
                2 => 73
            ),
            1 => array(
                0 => 31,
                1 => 49,
                2 => 73
            ),
            2 => array(
                0 => 31,
                1 => 51,
                2 => 73
            ),
            3 => array(
                0 => 39,
                1 => 41,
                2 => 73
            ),
            4 => array(
                0 => 39,
                1 => 49,
                2 => 73
            ),
            5 => array(
                0 => 39,
                1 => 51,
                2 => 73
        ),
        1 => array(
            0 => array(
                0 => 41,
                1 => 31,
                2 => 73
            ),
            1 => array(
                0 => 41,
                1 => 39,
                2 => 73
            ),
            2 => array(
                0 => 49,
                1 => 31,
                2 => 73
            ),
            3 => array(
                0 => 49,
                1 => 39,
                2 => 73
            ),
                etc ......
        )
    );
```

Manos function Output:

```
    array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(8) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      int(31)
      [1]=>
      int(41)
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      int(39)
      [1]=>
      int(41)
    }
    [2]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      int(31)
      [1]=>
      int(49)
    }
    [3]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      int(39)
      [1]=>
      int(49)
    }
    [4]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      int(31)
      [1]=>
      int(51)
    }
    [5]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      int(39)
      [1]=>
      int(51)
    }
    [6]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      int(31)
      [1]=>
      int(73)
    }
    [7]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      int(39)
      [1]=>
      int(73)
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(9) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      int(41)
      [1]=>
      int(31)
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      int(49)
      [1]=>
      int(31)
    }
    [2]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      int(51)
      [1]=>
      int(31)
    }
    [3]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      int(41)
      [1]=>
      int(39)
    }
    [4]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      int(49)
      [1]=>
      int(39)
    }
    [5]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      int(51)
      [1]=>
      int(39)
    }
    [6]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      int(41)
      [1]=>
      int(73)
    }
    [7]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      int(49)
      [1]=>
      int(73)
    }
    [8]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      int(51)
      [1]=>
      int(73)
    }
  }
  [2]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      int(73)
      [1]=>
      int(31)
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      int(73)
      [1]=>
      int(39)
    }
    [2]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      int(73)
      [1]=>
      int(41)
    }
    [3]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      int(73)
      [1]=>
      int(49)
    }
    [4]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      int(73)
      [1]=>
      int(51)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($a as $first_group_key => $first_group) {
    foreach ($a as $second_group_key => $second_group) {
        if ($second_group_key == $first_group_key) {
            continue;
        }
        $i = count($b[$first_group_key]);
        foreach ($second_group as $second_value) {
            foreach ($first_group as $first_key => $first_value) {
                $b[$first_group_key][$i][0] = $first_value;
                $b[$first_group_key][$i][1] = $second_value;
                $i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Manos. But this doesn't work for me. I've got dynamic arrays (see above for example), so your static function won't work for me.

Comment: I realised, that it unfortunatly only works if the array has two parent array keys. What I need is a dynamic function no matter how many parent array keys and children values the dynamic array has.

Comment: you got me curious, so I tried to see how it exactly works. Now it works as you wish!

Comment: This is a nice solution, but unfortunatly not what i look for (See above for expected example output). For simple explanation: I'm looking for a array solution, which combines every array value width each other array values grouped by array keys. It should not matter, if the count of grouped values is different. So it have to be a dynamic function.

Comment: what is above is very close to what you want (I think).
I suggest you to squeeze your brain a bit to change it accordingly ;)
A good idea is to put in your code echo '<pre>'; print_r ($b); echo '</pre>'; to manually see what's being printed!

Comment: Sure, this is approach. But it's not close to what i'm looking for. It's limited to two values and its not dynamic. Please check my updated answer for the expected output conditions. The array is not always the same with the same count of array values.

Comment: I don't see anything static. That's an indication for something dynamic. You have a good basis to work on I believe. Stackoverflow is not for others to do your work. It's for you to get some help/direction to do it on your own ;)